# CSS floating action button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a button that other options pop out of when you hover over it. I've been searching for a way to do something like the screenshot below, but I wasn't able to do it. It's for a web page, so it needs to be done using HTML, CSS, and jQuery.

[image: Screenshot of button]

Comment: you should show your at least your working efforts here, it will produce an idea about the efforts you have consume to accomplish the tasks.

Comment: @Ahamedos please take a look at my answer when you have a chance. I included all parts of the solution—the main button, fly-out buttons, and the modals—using pure HTML and CSS, without JS.

Answer (score 22):

Here is an example using HTML and CSS to create a floating action button (without the hover effect).

```css
.kc_fab_main_btn {
  background-color: #F44336;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #F44336;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 36px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.kc_fab_main_btn:focus {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="kc_fab_main_btn">+</button>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zgr7z50c/1/)

And here is a simple floating action button jQuery plugin, in case you need it. But it is using on click trigger rather than hover.

[KC_FAB](https://github.com/katrincwl/kc_fab)

Comment: simple, just css - nice! +1

Comment: @Katrin your demo link not working is not working.

Answer (score 11):

The best tutorial for this purpose that I have found so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYFNaeEeCDI

Working demo example: https://verkkonet.com/downloads/demo.php?id=c9

```css
.fab-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fab-icon-holder {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #016fb9;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fab-icon-holder:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fab-icon-holder i {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #d23f31;
}

.fab-options {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 85% bottom;
}

.fab:hover+.fab-options,
.fab-options:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.fab-options li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fab-label {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  align-self: center;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fab-container">
  <div class="fab fab-icon-holder">
    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="fab-options">
    <li>
      <span class="fab-label">Documentation</span>
      <div class="fab-icon-holder">
        <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="fab-label">Video Tutorials</span>
      <div class="fab-icon-holder">
        <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="fab-label">Live Chat</span>
      <div class="fab-icon-holder">
        <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="fab-label">Feedback</span>
      <div class="fab-icon-holder">
        <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The entire example is from: https://verkkonet.com/.
The YouTube video tutorial is great to learn how to do this.

Comment: Thank you! This is an awesome example.  If you are wrapping an anchor element around the icon and label add the flex-inline class to it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @BrunoLeitão there is a small part of the blank space between the red question mark and the other icons that are revealed where if you don't move your cursor up quick enough, they all hide again

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell you can fix it if you change .fab-options bottom from 70px to 60px and add: .fab-options li:last-child { padding-bottom: 15px; }

Answer (score 6):

### UPDATE 5/3/2021

I revisited my solution today and added the final touches to those parts I left incomplete yesterday. I also added several additional enhancements and stylistic improvements. Now, for the `#mega-button` parent, it uses a gradient background but then smoothly transitions to a faded blue-gray background color by using an oversized gradient and transitioning the `background-position` property. I also decrease the size of this button on hover as I rotate and increase the size of the child `.sub-button` elements, to give the appearance of the `.sub-button` elements rolling out from behind the `#mega-button`.

To make the transition feel more smooth and natural, I also added a slight `transition-delay` between each of the `.sub-button` elements to create a waterfall effect rather than them all rolling out on top of each other. I achieved this and also the unique position per `.sub-button` using a for loop in my SCSS, and iterating in reverse for the `transition-delay` to have the right-most button animate out first.

I also utilize some glassmorphism styles to give the `#mega-button` just the slightest bit of a a frosted glass look as the buttons roll out from behind it: `backdrop-filter: blur(4px)`

When you click on any of the child buttons, they trigger their associated modal via `:target`. The modals themselves all offer several pure-HTML/CSS ways to close the modal:

- clicking the translucent background behind the modal
- clicking the close button "x" in the top-right
- clicking the "Cancel" action button

Each modal is entirely unique and is triggered by its associated `.sub-button`. I built a bit of a system behind the modal styles as well, with global styles for the `.modal-content`, `.modal-header`, and `.modal-body`, as well as contextual styles for the `.modal-close` class, which displays as the clickable/cancellable backdrop behind the modal when inserted within the modal's main element, whereas it displays as the "x" in the top-right corner when included within the `.modal-content` element. Clicking either will close the modal.

Two final nice-to-haves I added today:

- Styles for a "new post" form with dynamic styles to intelligently produce the desired amount of spacing, as well as generic styles for a short alert modal, used for the Archive and Delete modals
- A hover tooltip which displays over the `#mega-button`. This tooltip cannot be clicked and does not functionally obstruct any content behind it as it has its `pointer-events` property set to `none`. This fades to `opacity: 0` both when the `#mega-button` or any of its descendants are being hovered over or when a modal is open, via the general sibling combinator (`~`).

Here is the finished product:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
.modal .modal-content .modal-body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.warning {
  display: block !important;
  padding: 12px 15px !important;
  background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.25) !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  color: #e53935 !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
.warning > i {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
#mega-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: default;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
  will-change: width;
}
#mega-button > .tooltip {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -9px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 2px rgba(120, 144, 156, 0.5));
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(120, 144, 156, 0.1);
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #1e4989;
  -webkit-animation: tooltip-hover;
          animation: tooltip-hover;
  /* @keyframes duration | easing-function | delay |
  iteration-count | direction | fill-mode | play-state | name */
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate both tooltip-hover;
          animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate both tooltip-hover;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  will-change: opacity;
}
#mega-button > .tooltip::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
#mega-button::before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  background: 100% 100%/250% 100% #fff linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 33%, #2c92c8 66%, #892cc8) no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px #1a237e;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  will-change: transform, background-color, box-shadow;
}
#mega-button > .sub-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #2c92c8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px #1a237e;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transition: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  will-change: transform, transition-duration;
}
#mega-button > .sub-button::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: inherit;
  will-change: transform;
}
#mega-button > .sub-button#buttons--write::before {
  content: "";
}
#mega-button > .sub-button#buttons--archive::before {
  content: "";
}
#mega-button > .sub-button#buttons--delete::before {
  content: "";
}
#mega-button:hover {
  width: calc(50px + 2px + 123px);
}
#mega-button:hover::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.675);
  padding-right: 2px;
  box-shadow: 7.5px 7.5px 20px -10px rgba(55, 71, 79, 0);
  background: -100% 100%/250% 100% rgba(144, 164, 174, 0.625) linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 33%, #2c92c8 66%, #892cc8) no-repeat;
}
#mega-button:hover::after {
  width: 200px;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button::before {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px + 0% + 0px + 2px), -50%) scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px + 0% + 0px + 2px), -50%) scale(1.18);
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px + 100% + 5px + 2px), -50%) scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px + 100% + 5px + 2px), -50%) scale(1.18);
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px + 200% + 10px + 2px), -50%) scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px + 200% + 10px + 2px), -50%) scale(1.18);
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:hover {
  background-color: #3949ab;
}
#mega-button:hover > .sub-button:hover::before {
  transform: scale(0.85);
}
#mega-button:hover .tooltip, .modal:target ~ #mega-button .tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}
.modal > .modal-close::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 0.5);
}
.modal .modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.modal .modal-content > div:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
.modal .modal-content > div:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
.modal .modal-content > .modal-close::after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #546e7a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(37.5%, -37.5%);
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}
.modal .modal-content > .modal-close ~ div:first-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.modal .modal-content > .modal-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #263238;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-header {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background-color: #37474f;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body p {
  color: #455a64;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body p + p, .modal .modal-content .modal-body p + .modal-actions {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body > :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body label {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body label:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input, .modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:focus, .modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input {
  display: block;
  width: 235px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  background-color: #303f9f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #455a64;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  will-change: width, padding, background-color, border-radius, font-size, font-weight;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  will-change: font-size, font-weight, color;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  will-change: font-size, font-weight, color;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  will-change: font-size, font-weight, color;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  -ms-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  will-change: font-size, font-weight, color;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:focus, .modal .modal-content .modal-body input:valid {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: text;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, .modal .modal-content .modal-body input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:focus:-moz-placeholder, .modal .modal-content .modal-body input:valid:-moz-placeholder {
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:focus::-moz-placeholder, .modal .modal-content .modal-body input:valid::-moz-placeholder {
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder, .modal .modal-content .modal-body input:valid:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body input:valid:not(:focus) {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea {
  display: block;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  resize: vertical;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px #37474f;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #455a64;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #78909c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #607d8b;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -15px #455a64;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-out;
  will-change: box-shadow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a.write, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button.write {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a.archive, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button.archive {
  background-color: #ef6c00;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a.delete, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button.delete {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a.write, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button.write {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -15px #0d47a1;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a.archive, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button.archive {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -15px #bf360c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a.delete, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button.delete {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -15px #b71c1c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a:hover, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px #455a64;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a:hover.write, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button:hover.write {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px #0d47a1;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a:hover.archive, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button:hover.archive {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px #bf360c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a:hover.delete, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button:hover.delete {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px #b71c1c;
}
.modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a + a, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions a + button, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button + a, .modal .modal-content .modal-body .modal-actions button + button {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
.modal:target {
  display: block;
}
@-webkit-keyframes tooltip-hover {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5px));
  }
}
@keyframes tooltip-hover {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5px));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/07afc061fe.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="modal-write" class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
    <div class="modal-header">New Post</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="modal-write-title">Post Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="modal-write-title" placeholder=" Give your post a name..." required>
      <label for="modal-write-body">Post Body</label>
      <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="10" id="modal-write-body" placeholder="What would you like to say?" required></textarea>
      <div class="modal-actions">
        <a href="#">Cancel</a>
        <button class="write">Post</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal-archive" class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
    <div class="modal-header">Archive Post</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Would you like to archive your post?</p>
      <div class="modal-actions">
        <a href="#">Cancel</a>
        <button class="archive">Archive</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal-delete" class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <a href="#" class="modal-close"></a>
    <div class="modal-header">Delete Post</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Are you sure you want to delete your post?</p>
      <p class="warning"><i class="far fa-exclamation-circle"></i>This cannot be undone.</p>
      <div class="modal-actions">
        <a href="#">Cancel</a>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mega-button">
  <div class="tooltip">Hover me!</div>
  <a class="sub-button" id="buttons--write" href="#modal-write"></a>
  <a class="sub-button" id="buttons--archive" href="#modal-archive"></a>
  <a class="sub-button" id="buttons--delete" href="#modal-delete"></a>
</div>
```

Here is the finished CodePen for this solution in all its original "Sass"-y glory: https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/082f4ee58d234501757b8d6a748c514b?editors=0100

All of the dynamic variables in this SCSS could rather simply be converted to CSS custom properties if you prefer to keep all those calculations dynamic in the final CSS.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Please take a look at my updated solution when you have a chance. I've included a link to my original code on CodePen (with original SCSS used). All styles are pure CSS friendly. The only JS include I used was Font Awesome 5 to include some custom iconography.

Comment: Just a heads up: this is not very accessible. Displaying the options with a touchscreen is unreliable at best, impossible at worst.

Comment: @NatRiddle I agree with you. However, the question specified the `hover` state and not the `focus` state or I would have made that adjustment as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example code on my try for floating buttons on hover (HTML & CSS).

```css
.flBtnCntr {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px
}
.flBtnBox {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2978d3;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer
}
.flBtnBox.big {
  background-color: #2978d3;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}
.flBtnBox.small {
  animation: showBtn 150ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: #363636;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.flBtnBox.small:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 150ms
}
.flBtnBox.small:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 300ms
}
@keyframes showBtn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
.flBtnBox.big:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(41,120,211,0.4)
}
.flBtnBox.small:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
.flBtns {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  align-items: center
}
.flBtnCntr:hover .flBtns {
  display: inline-flex
}
```

```html
<div class="flBtnCntr">
  <button class="flBtnBox big">+</button>
  <div class="flBtns">
    <button class="flBtnBox small">+</button>
    <button class="flBtnBox small">+</button>
    <button class="flBtnBox small">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code pen link:
[Demo](https://codepen.io/prakashmari/pen/wvKrdMQ)

Comment: You didn't make a modal, so I can't give you the bounty, but I might award you a separate second bounty

Answer (score 4):

## `:target` implementation with modal

Modal implementation with a bit of styling from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209244/how-to-do-a-floating-action-button-using-css#62333215)

```css
.fab-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fab-icon-holder {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fab-icon-holder:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fab-icon-holder i {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #3F51B5;
}

.fab-options {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 85% left;
}

.fab:hover+.fab-options,
.fab-options:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.fab-options li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
}

:target {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

#modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}

#modal .content {
  margin: 1em;
}

#modal #close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="fab-container">
  <div class="fab fab-icon-holder">
    <i class="fas fa-question material-icons">add</i>
  </div>
  <ul class="fab-options">
    <li>
      <div class="fab-icon-holder">
        <a href="#modal" style="all:unset"><i class="fas fa-file-alt material-icons">launch</i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="modal">
  <div class="content">
    This is a modal
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i id="close">×</i></a>
</div>
```

Here's my old one (albeit with poor styling):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.button {
  color: white;
}

.parent-button {
  box-shadow:0 0 3px #3F51B5;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.child-button {
  box-shadow:0 0 3px black;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding:0.75em;
  opacity:0;
}
.child-button a{
  color:white;
}
.parent-button:hover~.child-button{
  opacity:1;
}

.child-button:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
:target {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

#modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}

#modal .content {
  margin: 1em;
}

#modal #close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="parent-button button">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </div>
  
    <div class="child-button button">
      <a href="#modal"><i class="material-icons">fullscreen</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal">
  <div class="content">
    This is a modal
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i id="close">×</i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any code prewritten or are you just asking for a tutorial?

If the former, here is some idea of how you can structure your code for this to work:

```
var el = $('a.button'); // the element you want to hover over
var hi = $('div.hidden'); // the div containing the hidden buttons

el.hover(function(){
    //do this when the mouse hovers over the link, eg
    hi.show('slide',{direction:'right'},250);
}, function(){
    //do this when the mouse leaves the link, eg
    hi.hide('slide',{direction:'left'},250);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to this question.

**Preview:** https://jsfiddle.net/rp0jg576/53/

HTML and CSS code:

```css
i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  /* 24px preferred icon size */
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#btn {
  display: none;
}

.button-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}


/* link and link-parent */

.link-parent {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.link-item {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-name: move-up;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/* control click */

#btn:checked~.link-parent {
  display: flex;
}


/* animation */

@keyframes move-up {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

#link-one {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

#link-two {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

#link-third {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

#link-forth {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='button-parent'>
  <input type="checkbox" id='btn'>
  <label for="btn" class='button'>
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
      </label>

  <div class="link-parent">
    <a href='#' class='link-item' id='link-one'>
      <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class='link-item' id='link-two'>
      <i class="material-icons">article</i>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class='link-item' id='link-third'>
      <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class='link-item' id='link-forth'>
      <i class="material-icons">room</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Slide in-out style

Type 1: Width adjusting from `0px` to a width that fits the content.

```css
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
}

.action-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 0px;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.action-btn {
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.action-parent {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  color: white;
}

.action-parent:hover+.child-container {
  width: 159px;
}

.action-child {
  padding: 0.75em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.child-container:hover {
  width: 159px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="action-container">
  <div class="action-parent action-btn">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="action-child action-btn">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </div>
    <div class="action-child action-btn">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </div>
    <div class="action-child action-btn">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Type 2: The whole child action button container is sliding in:

```css
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
}

.action-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child-container {
  display: flex;
}

.action-btn {
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.action-parent {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.action-parent:hover+.child-container .action-child {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.action-child {
  transition: 1s;
  padding: 0.75em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="action-container">
  <div class="action-parent action-btn">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="action-child action-btn">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </div>
    <div class="action-child action-btn">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </div>
    <div class="action-child action-btn">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```